# behavioural graph possible in R/ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

Hoping you guys can help me, I'm desperately trying to create a graph similar to the one attached here.

[image: proposed graph]

The full vertical bars represent experience shared across all Areas (and likely to trigger the events in each area). I apologize for the lack of color in the plot. For my current purposes, the labels on each don't matter, it only matters that I be able to add them later.

Here are some sample data. I am currently labeling all of the vertical bars as "Movement One" and all of the smaller bars as "Movement Two" to keep things as clear as I can:

```
move_one <-
  data.frame(
    start = c(10 , 1000, 3000)
    , end = c(250, 1500, 4500)
    , label = "Movement One"
  )

move_two <-
  data.frame(
    ind = rep(1:3, each = 3)
    , start = c(275, 1600, 3800
                , 20, 1010, 3010
                , 240, 1400, 4400)
    , end =   c(295, 1750, 4400
                , 30, 1700, 3600
                , 290, 1800, 4500)
    , label = "Movement Two"
  )
```

Give

```
  start  end        label
1    10  250 Movement One
2  1000 1500 Movement One
3  3000 4500 Movement One
```

and

```
  ind start  end        label
1   1   275  295 Movement Two
2   1  1600 1750 Movement Two
3   1  3800 4400 Movement Two
4   2    20   30 Movement Two
5   2  1010 1700 Movement Two
6   2  3010 3600 Movement Two
7   3   240  290 Movement Two
8   3  1400 1800 Movement Two
9   3  4400 4500 Movement Two
```

respectively (these do *not* match the hand drawn graph here).

Comment: Could you at least use two different colors corresponding to Movement 1 and Movement 2. It is also hard to understand what the vertical "bands" correspond to. And please, remove the jokes from the question.

Comment: Apologies it isn't very clear, I was on a train with only a pen unfortunately so tried to do diagonal and horizontal shading to show te difference - admittedly this isn't clear. the vertical bars refer to instances of one of two movements (Movement 1 = diagonal shading, Movement 2 = horizontal shading). The horizontal bars are instances of when an area in a scene was looked at and essentially I wanted to overlay the two datasets. As for jokes, I'm not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: I will take a stab at editing the question, but you should not edit to change the underlying question (moving from the basic graph to a specific aspect). Now that you have a base, ask a new question to follow up on the detail (and link between the two).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"This is R. There is no if. Only how." -Simon Blomberg

Basically, we just need to pass each component in to `ggplot` separately. First, we use `geom_rect` to create the underlying vertical bars. Then add the horizontal lines for each area with `geom_hline`. Finally, add the small boxes on top with another `geom_rect`. Polish with axis labels and any other theme settings you would like from there.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_rect(
    aes(xmin = start
        , xmax = end
        , fill = label
        , ymin = 0
        , ymax = 4)
    , move_one
  ) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = ind)
             , move_two) +
  geom_rect(
    aes(xmin = start
        , xmax = end
        , fill = label
        , ymin = ind - 1/3
        , ymax = ind + 1/3)
    , move_two
  ) +
  xlab("Time (milliseconds)") +
  ylab("Area")
```

Gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that Mark, it gave me the motivation and inspiration I needed to attempt this project one last time. I've been playing around with your example but I just wanted to clarify some parts of the code. In ind = rep(1:3, each = 3), would I change 1:3 to increase the number of areas? I have ~37. Also, what does each = 3 achieve? On each line of area there are currently 3 green blocks, is it related to this? In my actual data there will be varying numbers of green blocks on each line. Currently I'm trying to have text labels on the y axis instead of 0,1,2..loving ggplot2 though!

Comment: I am assuming that you have the data in hand somewhere already. If you are digitizing it (i.e., transcribing from paper records), I would **not** enter the data in R -- I would save the data as a csv (e.g., in LibreOffice, Google Sheets, or Excel). To see what each piece of the code does, run them separately (`each` tells `rep` how many times in a row to put each component of the vector it is repeating; using `times` instead repeats the full vector that many times). Entering real data like this gets messy (and error-prone) quickly.

Comment: For data labels, you *can* use a factor as the y-axis. However, it will make it harder to control the vertical bars behind it. Instead, I would plot using the factor index (the number associated with the factor level) then modify the scale to show your labels. e.g. `scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:length(levels(move_two$ind)), labels = levels(move_two$ind))`